# Managing the state of Python Add-In extension

Tags: arcpy, python-addin, extensions

I have a python add-in that includes a toolbar and an extension. A button on the toolbar should turn extension on and off.

A code for the button:

```
class Switch(object):
# Implementation for Sample_addin.btnSwitch (Button)
def __init__(self):
    self.enabled = True
    self.checked = False

def onClick(self):
    if not self.checked:
        self.checked = True
        print "Extension ON"
        # extExtension.__init__()
        extExtension.enabled = True
    else:
        self.checked = False
        print "Extension OFF"
        extExtension.enabled = False
```

A code for the extension:

```
class Extension(object):
# Implementation for Sample_addin.extExtension (Extension)
def __init__(self):
    self.enabled = True
    print 'Initialized'
# and so on...
```

And a part of config.xml:

```
<Extension  autoLoad="true"
            category="Tool"
            class="Extension"
            description="description"
            id="Sample_addin.extExtension"
            name="Extension"
            productName="Extension"
            showInExtensionDialog="true" />''
```

Everything seems to be OK. When I click the button, it freezes in 'checked' state and the extension gets marked in Extension dialog (Customize -> Extensions). But after this the extension doesn't start working (I have many functions in it like 'onCreate' and so on).

If I toggle it manually in Extensions dialog - everything is OK, it works.

And the reverse case - when the Extension works and I want to switch it off by clicking on the button, it only changes its state in Extension dialog but not in reality.

I've tried to reinitialize the extension by calling `extExtension.__init__()`. This gave me nothing (and no errors too, only this print statement).

How to track the state of an extension in python add-in and change it?